# MS access replace null or zero values with nearest non-zero row

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a sample dataset like this

```
 Group  Age Value
    A   1   
    A   2   0
    A   3   20
    B   1   0
    B   2   0
    B   3   25
    B   4   0
    B   5   0
    B   6   50
```

For each distinct value in `Group`, replace null or zero `Value`.
Ideal output will be

```
 Group  Age Value
    A   1   20
    A   2   20
    A   3   20
    B   1   25
    B   2   25
    B   3   25
    B   4   25
    B   5   50
    B   6   50
```

**UPDATE**

This seems to do the trick

```
UPDATE test
SET [Value] = nz(DMin(
    "[Value]", 
    "test", 
    "[Group] = '" & [Group] & "' AND 
     [Age] < " & [Age] & " AND 
     [Value] <> 0 AND [Value] IS NOT NULL"
),
 DMax(
    "[Value]", 
    "test", 
    "[Group] = '" & [Group] & "' AND 
     [Age] > " & [Age] & " AND 
     [Value] <> 0 AND [Value] IS NOT NULL"
))
WHERE [Value] = 0 OR [Value] IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this (in MsAccess SQL a column can be derived from a subquery returning  or one value - or no rows):

```
select 
     tactl.[Group], 
     tactl.Age, 
     (  select trepl.[Value]
        from test trepl
        where tactl.[Group]=trepl.[Group]
              and nz(trepl.[Value],0)<>0
              and abs(tactl.Age-trepl.Age)=
                      ( select MIN(abs(ta.Age-tb.Age)) as MinDistanceFound 
                        from    test ta
                                inner join
                                test tb
                                on (ta.[Group]=tb.[Group]  and nz(tb.[Value],0) <> 0)
                       where (ta.[Group]=tactl.[Group]  and ta.[Age]=tactl.[Age])
                    )
      )  as [Value]
from test tactl
```

`GROUP` and `VALUE` can be reserved words in most SQL implementations (they are in Access); try to use other words for them (I put them in brackets to overcome issues)

Comment: `tc.Age>=t.Age` can only search for succeeding records. Is it possible to do it in both preceding and succeeding? And pick the one with minimal distance?

Comment: In my sample data, if Group B Age 6 is null, then above method doesn't work.

Comment: Can you define 'minimal distance'? Is it where the Age is closest?

Comment: If I take out the 50 in the last row for `Group=B Age=6`, ideally  `value`  of last three rows should be replaced by 25 (Group=B Age=3)

Comment: replaced it with a minimum 'distance' version

Answer (score 0):

Consider domain aggregation such as `DMin` in order to have an updateable query:

```
UPDATE test
SET [Value] = DMin(
    "[Value]", 
    "test", 
    "[Group] = '" & [Group] & "' AND 
     [Age] > " & [Age] & " AND 
     [Value] <> 0 AND [Value] IS NOT NULL"
)
WHERE [Value] = 0 OR [Value] IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for my sample. But if I take out the 50 in the last row for Group=B Age=6, ideally value of last three rows should be replaced by 25 (Group=B Age=3) . Is it possible to do so via `DMin`?

Comment: The only thing I can come up with right now is to run the code first and then change `[Age] >` to `[Age] <` and run it again.

Comment: You may then need to run two update queries to forward look and then backward look for any zeroes/NULLs leftovers as your final solution showed.